# Total sum of two columns trigger on SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, triggers

Well as title says, I'm trying to set a column value based on the sum of two columns in the same table, I mean, I have a row on a table where I have some attributes "capital,income,mat_expense,other_expense,net_profit" I will be updating this row everytime I sell a new product or register some payments, when I sell a new product, I will update the "income" attribute adding the sale price, when I register a mat_expense(raw material expense) I will update that attribut adding the new expense price the same action with other_expense, my point is I want to calculate the net_profit of my sell, If i sell 20$ and I spend 10$ on raw material, I want my net_profit attribute to be 10, and make the same operation everytime I update de the table, the same thing I wanna do with the "capital" attribute (income - (mat_expense + other_expense), that is basiclly what I need to do, I've been reading this operation should be done by a "trigger" on sqlite, I have been reading some post but I don't get how to fit it to my case, can you guys give me a hands with this? Example:

```
| capital | income | mat_expense | other_expense | net_profit |
    5         20         10              5             10
```

By the way, this is a consult, could be possible to make a trigger which make an attribute acts as a accumulator? as I explained before, I'll be upgrading some attributes, adding new values,everytime I do that, I need to consult the currently value save it in a Variable then I sum the new value, which I think It's not much efficient.

Thank you so much by reading and I really thank any help you guys can give me.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can use expressions to define new columns, ie:

```
select 
   income, 
   mat_expense, 
   other_expense, 
   income - (mat_expense + other_expense) as capital 
from your_table;
```

You will get the 4rd column called 'capital'

As for the second question - you should use such calculated virtual columns whenever it's possible. Expressions may be quite complex and include SQL functions, and even include subqueries. For example you can add a column with minimal value from other table rows correlated with current row from the first table.

Generally SQL language is about transforming source sets of data into other representations, some tables into others.

When you can't calculate result set in single SQL statement, then you may have to calculate intermediate temporary data/variables, may be via temp tables/cursors etc, but it is the last thing one should do. Still we can't avoid it sometimes

Comment: I'm not sure about your example Mixas, I already created the tables and columns, I was thinking in a trigger, but you mean I can declare that on my CREATE TABLE command? I mean, in the momento where I'm creating the table?

Comment: No, I mean that you can use 'calculated virtual columns' in SELECT statements. Values in such columns will change as soon as source data change. SELECT statement usually happens when you create a cursor

Comment: Some more on this matter: in a DB there are source data (TABLES), and views of that data. SELECT is some kind of virtual table created from source data (tables, single SELECT may even join several tables in common result table). SELECT is such view, calculated each time the source data change (of course you need to re-query a cursor to get updated data)

Comment: That's thee point Mixaz, I'm trying to avoid the selects, I'm using many consults to database when I want to set one or two values on a table, which I think its no the best way, as you're planning, I guess I need to do an update to the table with the new income value or expense vale and after that ,I need to make another consult select to set the value to capital, I need to set the value to net_profit as well, so I will need to make another select to set the net_profit value? I really appreciate your suggestion, but I think the best and efficient way to do what I'm trying to implement is creat

Comment: Yes, if you want to store that calculations persistently (ie to not recalculate on each select), then you can use UPDATE statement (and you need to create additional columns in advance, in CREATE TABLE statement). You can update several columns at once. I do not remember the update statement exactly, but you may consult with docs. Android's Database.update() allows specifying several fields as well.

Comment: And I do not understand "I need to make another consult select to set the value to capital" - in my approach capital is not a column table, it's a calculated value thus doesn't need updating. It is calculated each time you extract it with a SELECT

Comment: As I already said, SQL is about transforming data from one presentation to another. You can use calculated columns in SELECTs, or create temporary (or persistent, doesn't matter) tables for calculated values (and update them when source data change). By the way, even you place calculated values into columns of tables, to extract them (with a cursor) you'll be performing a SELECT statement anyway. Storing results of calculations in DB may be used to avoid calculations overhead.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm getting bored with this discussion, looks like I speaking about the same thing in cycle. I will not get back to this discussion. Good luck